# axis2 xsd:date format issue

Tags: apache-axis

I have WSDL as follows:

```
< xsd:simpleType name="USER_ACT_STRDT_TypeDef">
  < xsd:annotation>
 < xsd:documentation>USER_ACT_STRDT is a date.< /xsd:documentation>
  < /xsd:annotation>
  < xsd:restriction base="xsd:date">
    < xsd:pattern value="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"/>
  < /xsd:restriction>
< /xsd:simpleType>
```

When I generate the STUB (using Axis2 1.5.3), the generated stub (ADB Data Binding) has the following source code :

```
public void setUSER_ACT_STRDT_TypeDef(Date param) {

if (ConverterUtil.convertToString(param).matches("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")) {

this.localUSER_ACT_STRDT_TypeDef=param; } else { throw new java.lang.RuntimeException();
} }
```

This method always throws RuntimeException because the ConverterUtil.convertToString() method returns a String in a different format than "yyyy-mm-dd". It returns the date by appending +5.30 as 2011-03-21+05:30.

I tried passing the date in different formats but same result for all.

Can any one suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5219937/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: Also, I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562).

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
if (ConverterUtil.convertToString(param).matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"))
```

will work only with one of date representations available. In [WSDL date specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date) you will find that `2011-03-21+05:30` is also correct date representation, it simply include time zone as +5 hours and 30 minutes offset to UTC.

Axis2 by default generate dates with timezone but should be able to operate on other date formats.

To check if string starts with `YYYY-MM-DD` date you can use such code:

```
if (! sd.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.*"))
    throw new ParseException("Something is terribly wrong with date: " + sd, 0);
else
    {
    sd = sd.substring(0, 10);
    System.out.println("ok: '" + sd + "'");
    }
```

PS Do you escape `\d` as `\\d`?

PPS Why do you throw `RuntimeException`? There are much "better" exceptions like `ParseException` (used by JDK date parsing methods) or `IllegalArgumentException` (used by joda time library)